# Passing Links from CSV to Beautiful Soup Returns Attribute Error: No Attribute .read()

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of scraped links in the first column of a .csv file. I'm trying to iterate through each link so I can scrape additional data, however BeautifulSoup can't read the link. I've been searching for an hour but can't find the problem:

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'**

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_data(csv_file):
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')  
    for row in reader:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(row.read(), 'lxml'))

        # THINGS I'M SCRAPING ARE HERE #

        for data in zip(scrape1, scrape2, scrape3):
            writer.writerow(data)

with open(r"C:\etc.csv", 'r+') as file:
    scrape_data(file)
file.close()
```

Comment: 5th line should be `soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(row[i]), 'lxml')`

Comment: @t.m.adam 7 this is returning ValueError: unknown url type: ''

Comment: So `row[i]` is an empty string apparently. Also what is 7?

Comment: Typo! Nothing to do with 7. Anyway, the links are in the first column, so row[0], and they absolutely exist! I'm still scratching my head

Comment: :) ok, so why don't you `print(row[0])` to make sure?

Comment: if i `print(row)` it will return the entire row, however if i `print(row[0])` it returns an error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `row` is an empty list? Now i'm scratching my head..